# printing output in python to txt file

Tags: python

wrote a simple program and would like to print the output to a text file. I'm trying the following at the very top of my script:

```
python SagicorPremiumCalculator2.py > textfile.txt
```

But this is giving me a syntax error in idle. How is my syntax incorrect?

```
python SagicorPremiumCalculator2.py > textfile.txt

python SagicorPremiumCalculator2.py > textfile.txt
import openpyxl, os, sys
wb = openpyxl.load_workbook('example.xlsx')
Millar_sheet = wb.get_sheet_by_name('Millar')
client = []
output = []
print(os.getcwd())


for rowOfCellObjects in Millar_sheet['A2':'AA13']:
        for cellObj in rowOfCellObjects:
                #if cellObj.value != None:
                #print(cellObj.coordinate, cellObj.value)
                client.append(cellObj.value)
        #print(client[2]) #client name
        print(client[0]) #policy number
        print(client[9]) #license plate
        #output.append(client[0]) #1
        #output.append(client[9]) #2
        if client[12] != "Not Applicable":
            float(client[12])
            print('S.I. = ' + '$' + str("%0.2f" % client[12]))
            #output.append("%0.2f" % client[12]) #3
        else:
            print('S.I. ' + client[12])
            print('Basic = ' + '$' + str("%0.2f" % client[13]))
            #output.append("%0.2f" % client[13])#3
        if client[14] != None:
            print('Loading = ' + str(100*client[14]) + '%')
        else:
            print('No Loading')
        val = client[13]
        if client[14] == None:
            val = client[15]     #if there is no loading percentage, val becomes subtotal
        else:
            val += (val*client[14]) # a = a + b, adds 150 to 1000
        print('Subtotal = ' + '$' + str("%0.2f" % val))#good
        if client[16] != None:
            ATD = val*client[16] #discount amount 
            print('ATD = ' + str(100*client[16]) + '%, -$' + str("%0.2f" % ATD))
            val -= (val*client[16])
            print('$' + str("%0.2f" % val))
        if client[17] != None:
            val -= (val*client[17])
            SP = val*client[17] #Discount amount
            print('SP = ' + str(100*client[17]) + '%, -$' + str("%0.2f" % SP))
            print('$' + str("%0.2f" % val))
        if client[18] != None:
                val = (val+client[18])
                PAB = client[18]
                print('PAB = +$' + str(client[18]))
                print('$' + str("%0.2f" % val))
        if client[19] != None:
            NCD = val*client[19]
            val -= (val*client[19])#discount amount
            print('NCD = ' + str(100*client[19]) +'%, -$' + str("%0.2f" % NCD))
            print('$' + "%0.2f" % val)
        if client[20] != None:
            val = (val+client[20])
            print('W/S = +$' + str(client[20]))
            print('$' + "%0.2f" % val)
        if client[21] != None:
            val = (val+client[21])
            print('LOU = $' + str(client[21]))
            print('$' + "%0.2f" % val)
        if val < 750: #Applies minimum premium if val is under 750
            print("Minimum premium applied")
            val = 750

        print('Pre-tax Premium is ' + '$' + str("%0.2f" % val)) #good 
        if client[23] == 0: #Client over 65, not being charged tax
                print('According to Sagicor speadsheet, client over 65')
        else:
                PreTax = val*0.06
                val = (PreTax+val)
                print('Premium Tax = +$' + str("%0.2f" % PreTax)) #good
                print('$' + "%0.2f" % val)
        if client[25] != None:
                print('RS = +$' + str(client[25]))
                val = (val+client[25])
                print('Total = $' + str("%0.2f" % val))
                #if val == client[26]:
                        #print('Sagicor\'s total agrees with calculated total - top')
                #else:
                        #print('Premium does not agree - top')

        else:
                print('Roadside assistance NOT included')
                print('Total = $' + str("%0.2f" % val))
                #if val == client[26]:
                        #print('Sagicor\'s total agrees with calculated total - bottom')
                #else:
                        #print('Premium does not agree - bottom')
        client = []
        output = []
        print('--- END OF ROW ---')
```

Comment: The syntax you have above is a shell script, not a python script.

Comment: Are you trying to do that *inside a Python script?* It's not valid Python, that's a shell command.

Comment: can you provide us the code of SagicorPreniumCalculator2.py ? What does it print when you are using it without redirecting the output in a file ?

Comment: You're doing it right. Can you be more specific on the error you meet ?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to write the output of your script in a file I see two options. 
The first one is to handle the writing in the python script :

```
#!/usr/bin/python
#I am here assuming that you use a Unix-like system (i.e. Not Windows )

file = open('textfile.txt','w')

... some code ...

file.write(myData +'\n')

#Don't forget to close the file at the end of the script
file.close()
```

N.B: the 'w' option creates the file if it not exists, but it aslo delete previous version of the file. If you want to add lines at the end of an existing file, you should use 'a' instead.
The '\n' is just here to create a new line.

The other option is the following : Simple use print statament in your script

```
#My Script
... some code ...
print MyData
```

and then, run your script in a shell **not in IDLE** with the following command :

```
python SagicorPremiumCalculator2.py > textfile.txt
```

If you are running Windows, you should definitely use the first option (because I am not sure the bash-style commands works in cmd ).

I hope this helps !

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to explain to me. I am working on windows and it works. I just need to play with how its formatted now.